# How to reference "not yet created" class instance in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

New to python and generally object-oriented programming. I have written a script to do some stuff and here is a very simplified version of it with its main structure.

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mw = Tk()
        button = Button(self.mw, text='Open', command=self.openfile)
        button.pack()
        self.anotherwd = []
        self.mw.mainloop()

    def openfile(self):
        x = float(input('Number:'))
        self.anotherwd.append(AnotherWindow(x))

class AnotherWindow:
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.aw = Toplevel()
        self.var = IntVar()
        self.numb = number
        label = Label(self.aw, text="Multiply by:")
        entry = Entry(self.aw, textvariable=self.var)
        button = Button(self.aw, text='Plot', command=self.plot)
        label.pack()
        entry.pack()
        button.pack()

    def plot(self):
        numb_change = self.numb * self.var.get()
        plotwd.plotvar = numb_change
        plotwd.plot_line()
        YetAnotherWindow()


class PlotWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.plotvar = 0
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
    def plot_line(self):
        example = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)
        self.ax.plot(example, self.plotvar*example)
        self.fig.show()

class YetAnotherWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.yaw = Toplevel()
        self.var_yaw = IntVar()
        label = Label(self.yaw, text="More numbers:")
        entry = Entry(self.yaw, textvariable=self.var_yaw)
        button = Button(self.yaw, text='Plot more', command=self.plot_another_line)
        label.pack()
        entry.pack()
        button.pack()
    def plot_another_line(self):
        example = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)
        plotwd.ax.plot(example, self.var_yaw.get() * plotwd.plotvar * example)
        plotwd.fig.show()


plotwd = PlotWindow()
gui = MainWindow()
```

In the 'MainWindow' it let's you import some data (here as a number as console-input) then in a 'AnotherWindow' you modify the data (here multiply it by a entered number) and it plots this modified data in a 'PlotWindow'. Afterwards you can do some stuff with it in 'YetAnotherWindow' (again some useless multiplication) and plot the result in the same 'PlotWindow'.

The problem is, that there is only one 'PlotWindow'-Object while I want to create an instance every time I press the button in 'AnotherWindow' with separate modified data and another 'YetAnotherWindow'-Instance.
Now I could do it like in 'MainWindow' where I append new instances to a list but then I don't know how to reference such an instance in a separate class like 'YetAnotherWindow', as the one attribute in that instance of 'PlotWindow' would not be created yet while initialising. I wan which is why I declared it "fixed" as 'plotwd' in the first place as a "workaround".

I think "inheritance" might be a relevant keyword but I can't get it to work that way. I might doing some things too complicated anyway, so I better ask before I do some massive rewriting in the actual code.

Thanks.

Edit 1: Also a (related?) problem is that if I close the plot window 'AnotherWindow' closes too and I REALLY don't want that, which is the primary reason I want to change things up.

Edit 2: Not working example how I imagine it would work.

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mw = Tk()
        button = Button(self.mw, text='Open', command=self.openfile)
        button.pack()
        self.anotherwd = []
        self.mw.mainloop()

    def openfile(self):
        x = float(input('Number:'))
        self.anotherwd.append(AnotherWindow(x))


class AnotherWindow:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.aw = Toplevel()
        self.var = IntVar()
        self.numb = number
        self.plotwindows = []
        self.yawindows = []
        label = Label(self.aw, text="Multiply by:")
        entry = Entry(self.aw, textvariable=self.var)
        button = Button(self.aw, text='Plot', command=self.plot)
        label.pack()
        entry.pack()
        button.pack()

    def plot(self):
        numb_change = self.numb * self.var.get()
        self.plotwindows.append(PlotWindow)
        self.plotwindows[-1].plotvar = numb_change
        self.plotwindows[-1].plot_line
        self.yawindows.append(YetAnotherWindow)


class PlotWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.plotvar = 0
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()

    def plot_line(self):
        example = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)
        self.ax.plot(example, self.plotvar*example)
        self.fig.show()


class YetAnotherWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.yaw = Toplevel()
        self.var_yaw = IntVar()
        label = Label(self.yaw, text="More numbers:")
        entry = Entry(self.yaw, textvariable=self.var_yaw)
        button = Button(self.yaw, text='Plot more', command=self.plot_another_line)
        label.pack()
        entry.pack()
        button.pack()

    def plot_another_line(self):
        example = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)
        gui.anotherwd[-1].plotwindows[-1].ax.plot(example, self.var_yaw.get() * gui.anotherwd[-1].plotwindows[-1].plotvar * example)
        gui.anotherwd[-1].plotwindows[-1].fig.show()


gui = MainWindow()
```

Also even if that would work, I would acess in "YetAnotherGui" the "last PlotWindow" and not the one it "belongs to".

Comment: Well, isn't it how I do it here anyways? What I want is not plotwd but plotwd[0], plotwd[1] and so on with their own separate class attributes depending on which data you feed to it in 'AnotherWindow' and which you can individually modify via 'YetAnotherWindow'. Might missunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Why isn't `plotwd[0]` not working for you?

Comment: Because I would have no idea how to get e.g. self.fig, self.ax of that individual class instance in a separate class like 'YetAnotherWindow'. I tried to rewrite it (see Edit 2), as I would imagine how it would work. But it a) looks horrible and not very Pythiasian or how the philosophy is called and b) does not work.

Comment: if `self.anotherwd[0]` is an instance of `AnotherWindow`, then `self.anotherwd[0].aw` is the toplevel, `self.anotherwd[0].plotwindows[0]` is an instance of `PlotWindow`, and so on. It's not complicated, and there's nothing unique about tkinter objects. This is just how python works.

Comment: I never said anything abouth tkinter objects and sorry if the tag misleads, but in this case I don't care about tkinter. What is important is the referencing (if that is even the right term in this case) of class instances which are called in other instances. And I can't belive that that whole "self.anotherwd[0].plotwindows[0]" would be the best way to do it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand your question.

Comment: The main question is - am I doing things right, in the sense of "efficient"? But thanks anyways, was never good at explaining myself. I will manage on my own.